# VBA Application.Run error (The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled)

Tags: excel, vba

New question:

My original question is answered and the solution is perfectly fine. However, this resulted in another question. Here is the process flow:

macroFile1 Sub1 (calls macroFile2 Sub3 and passes arguments) -> macroFile2 Sub3 (does some process and is expected to return multiple values to macroFile1 Sub1)

macroFile1 Sub1 is able to call macroFile2 Sub3, but macroFile2 Sub3 is not able to return values. I have tried the following methods:

method1:

```
'(macroFile1)
returnCodes = Application.Run("'" & macroFileName & "'!pasteCapture", _
thisWorkbookName, selectedFile, cmntText, workingSheet, cmntRowNum, cmntColNum, imgRowNum, imgColNum, size, clrTyp)
```

Error upon execution: Compile error: Can't assign to array

method2:

```
'(macroFile1)          
Sub1 
'(This sub is going to call macroFile2 Sub3, and macroFile2 Sub3 is going to do some process, and then return values to the following Sub2.)

Application.Run "'" & macroFileName & "'!pasteCapture", _
thisWorkbookName, selectedFile, cmntText, workingSheet, cmntRowNum, cmntColNum, imgRowNum, imgColNum, size, clrTyp
'thisWorkbookName is the absolute path of the file containing macroFile1. I am passing this to macroFile2 Sub3 so that I can call macroFile1 Sub2 from macroFile2 Sub3.

End Sub

Sub2 
'(I wrote this sub so that I can receive return codes from macroFile2 Sub3. This sub is right below macroFile1 Sub1.)

Sub getReturnCodes(extError, fileNotFound, opnError, worksheetNotFound, rowNotNumeric, rowOutOfScope, colNotNumeric, colOutOfScope, sizeNotNumeric, sizeOutOfScope, incorrectClrTyp, success)

If success = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Successful", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "Error", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub

'(macroFile2)
Sub3 
'(This sub will receive multiple arguments from macroFile1 Sub1, process them, and call macroFile1 Sub2 to pass multiple return values.)

'Some process...

Application.Run "'" & calledBy & "'!getReturnCodes", _
extError, fileNotFound, opnError, worksheetNotFound, rowNotNumeric, rowOutOfScope, colNotNumeric, colOutOfScope, sizeNotNumeric, sizeOutOfScope, incorrectClrTyp, success

End Sub
```

Error upon execution: The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

Please help. I want to pass multiple values as return values to macroFile1. I am allowed to pass them to either Sub1 or Sub2.

Original question:

I am getting an error while calling a macro from another macro file.
I have seen many similar posts and tried the suggested solutions; however, I am still getting the error.

Here is the code:

```
'The following program is supposed to call another program

Sub screenCapture_Click()

Dim selectedFile As String 'Full path of the selected file

Const rowNum As Integer = 1
Const colNum As Integer = 1
Const workingSheet As Integer = 1
Const size As Variant = 100
Const clrTyp As Variant = 1

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show = False Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            selectedFile = .SelectedItems(1)
            Application.Run ("'ScreenCapture子プログラム.xlsm'!pasteCapture (" & selectedFile & "," & rowNum & "," & colNum & "," & workingSheet & "," & size & "," & clrTyp & ")") **
            'This is where the error occors. Application.Run is able to open 'ScreenCapture子プログラム.xlsm', but it is not able to call the macro...**
        End If
End With

End Sub

'The above program calls the following program

Sub pasteCapture(selectedFile, rowNum, colNum, workingSheet, size, clrTyp)

Dim capture As Image 'Captured image
Dim capturesFile As Workbook

EnterCommentUserForm.Show
.
.
.

End Sub
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm   That's not how you pass arguments.  Also, Run doesn't open the file with the macro - it needs to already be open.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for sharing the link. I tried passing the arguments as shown on https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm this page (Application.Run "'" & TestWkbk.Name & "'!MacroNameHere", "parm1", "parm2"). But it just does not work...

Comment: What does it do instead of work?  Please update your post to add the modified call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look more like this:

```
Application.Run "'ScreenCapture子プログラム.xlsm'!pasteCapture", _
                  selectedFile, rowNum, colNum, workingSheet, size, clrTyp
```

This is a useful reference: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm

Note also the workbook with the macro being called must already be open.

Comment: Thank you Tim! Application.Run "'ScreenCapture子プログラム.xlsm'!pasteCapture", _
                  selectedFile, rowNum, colNum, workingSheet, size, clrTyp This solution works perfectly fine... What does it do instead of work? > It resulted in the error which I have mentioned in the subject line

Comment: Hello again! Sorry to reopen this thread... I could successfully call a macro from another file with your help. Now, I want to return some values to the original macro. If I run the macro with the same syntax mentioned in your solution, I get error 1004. I don't understand why my first macro can call the second macro, but the second macro cannot call the first one with the same syntax. Do you know any better way of returning values to the first macro?

Comment: The link I posted above has an example of how to call a function and get the return value.  If that's not working for you then it would be best to post a new question including a minimal example code set.

Comment: I will edit my question so that I can make the code easily recognizable...

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: Please post a new question: there is no need to append a new question onto your already-answered one.  From a quick look, your first method fails because VBA doesn't work like that.  If you want to return a value, then use a *Function* not a Sub, and if you want to return a bunch of values then you need to return them as an array.  When posting code, try to keep the line lengths so we're not scrolling left to right to read it: that makes it hard to follow.  Use the line-continuation to wrap the lines at a reasonable length.

Comment: Hello Tim... Thank you for your reply! I will post a new question which will be easier to read... BTW, I have tried using a function, but I still get the same error (The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.) Basically, it gets stuck at Application.Run...